# Sudoku Function returning array of identical boards

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I am writing a recursive Sudoku solver and I am having some issues with 2D array handling.  I included the function which is giving the trouble.  There are some unnecessary lines I was using for debugging in there.

```
- (Stack *)successors
{
    Stack *stack = [[Stack alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    temp = [self.board copy];
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            if ([self.board[x][y] isEqualToString:@""] ||
                [self.board[x][y] isEqualToString:@"."]) {

                NSLog(@"%d %d", x, y);

                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    NSLog(@"%d", i);
                    [temp[x] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] atIndex:y];
                    State *tempState = [[State alloc] initWithBoard:temp];
                    if ([tempState legal]) {
                        NSMutableArray *input = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:temp];
                        [stack push:input];
                        [stack push:input];
                        [test addObject:input];
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"test %@", test);
                int p = [stack size];
                for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [stack pop]);
                }
                return stack;
            }
        }
    }
    return stack;
}
```

essentially, it begins at the top of the array and if the space is empty, it tries putting in the number 1 through 9 and if it is legal, based on another function I wrote previously, it will input it in the temp array and add it to the stack.  I checked this and it works great.  However, after adding them all together, I NSLog to check the stack and find that all of the stacked arrays now begin with the number 9, the last number checked in the temp array.  I believe I am having some issue with keeping reference to the temp array, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help is great.